# iterating through nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nested, nested-loops

i have this object

```
var arr = {
  specss: [{
      moe: 1,
      spec: [{
          specID: 4,
          cat: [{
              catID: 6,
            }],
        },
        {
          specID: 11,
          cat: [{
              catID: 7,
            }],
        }],
    }],
};
```

I am trying to reduce it to a simpler form.

I have tried looping through them but I always get the first item in the spec not all the items inside

this is my desired output

```
[{
    moe: 1,
    spec: [
      {
        specID: 4,
        catID: 6,
      },
      {
        specID: 11,
        catID: 7,
      },
    ],
  }];
```

Comment: How exactly are you looping them? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] of your attempts. It looks like you just need a [`map`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) call. How will this “simpler form” work if there is more than one object in the `cat` arrays?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `arr` to be `arr.specss`, then loop over every `spec` of the resulting array, moving the `.catID` property of the first `cat` object into the `spec` object. Like this:

```js
var arr = {
  specss: [{
      moe: 1,
      spec: [{
          specID: 4,
          cat: [{
              catID: 6,
            }],
        },
        {
          specID: 11,
          cat: [{
              catID: 7,
            }],
        }],
    }],
};

arr = arr.specss;
for (const specs of arr) {
  for (const spec of specs.spec) {
    spec.catID = spec.cat[0].catID;
    delete spec.cat;
  }
}
console.log(arr)
```